# Does BERT pretrain only on masked tokens?

Tags: bert

I was a bit confused on the details of the Masked Language Model in BERT pretraining. Does the model only predict the masked tokens for the purposes of pretraining or does it predict it for all tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, they only predict the masked tokens.

According to the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) in section 3.1:

> In order to train a deep bidirectional representation, we simply mask some percentage of the input
> tokens at random, and then predict those masked
> tokens. We refer to this procedure as a “masked
> LM” (MLM), although it is often referred to as a
> Cloze task in the literature (Taylor, 1953). In this
> case, the final hidden vectors corresponding to the
> mask tokens are fed into an output softmax over
> the vocabulary, as in a standard LM. In all of our
> experiments, we mask 15% of all WordPiece tokens in each sequence at random. In contrast to
> denoising auto-encoders (Vincent et al., 2008), we
> only predict the masked words rather than reconstructing the entire input.